# объясните суть работы с HTML-сущностью и объектом в js

Tags: javascript

В результате работы функции в console.log я могу получать объекты

```
init [input#w0.cart_auth_username.form-control, context: input#w0.cart_auth_username.form-control]
```

либо html-сущность - простой кусок html-кода

И вот, допустим мне надо очистить значение этого инпута, а вместо init, к которому я могу применить .val('') мне приходит этот инпут в хтмл-виде и соответственно .val('') я не применю.

Объясните, пожалуйста, можно ли преобразовывать одно в другое и как правильно писать функции, чтоб ожидаемо получить либо первое либо второе. А также имеет ли значение при этом всём использование jquery?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> init [input#w0.cart_auth_username.form-control, context: input#w0.cart_auth_username.form-control]
> ```

В данном случае вывод соответствует объекту jQuery, следовательно у него есть все методы присутствующие в jQuery.

Если приходит обычный HTMLElement, то для получения объекта jQuery достаточно передать его в `$(...)` в качестве аргумента.